# I am trying to add custom term in text moderation service of azure for zho_chs language. but returning zho_chs is invalide code

Tags: azure, text, detection, cjk, azure-cognitive-services

I Given "OriginalText" as input to detect offensive terms and it detected the language as zho_chs. below text is response from API

```
{
  "OriginalText": "some profanity in zho_chs\r\n",
  "NormalizedText": "some profanity in zho_chs\r\n",
  "Misrepresentation": null,
  "Language": "**zho_chs**",
  "Terms": null,
  "Status": {
    "Code": 3000,
    "Description": "OK",
    "Exception": null
  },
  "TrackingId": <my trackingID>
}
```

But Now I am trying to add the custom term to be detected for language **zho_chs** below is the response from custom term adding. except zho_chs we are able to add for spa,fra,jpn,eng,deu. only having problem with zho_chs.

> The language code is invalid: zho_chs.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Language Detection supported Chinese Simplified language code is `zh_chs` and not `zho_chs`

As per [this](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes-keyword.php?SearchTerm=zho&SearchType=ALL&Submit=Go), `zho` is `ISO 639-2 Language Code` while Azure Language Detection conform to `ISO 639-1 Language Code` identifiers.

You can refer to [Languages supported by Language Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/language-detection/language-support)

> The Language Detection feature can detect a wide range of languages, variants, dialects, and some regional/cultural languages, and return detected languages with their name and code. The returned language code parameters conform to [BCP-47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) standard with most of them conforming to [ISO-639-1](https://www.iso.org/iso-639-language-codes.html) identifiers.

**Note:** Languages are added as new [model versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/language-detection/how-to/call-api#specify-the-language-detection-model) are released. The current model version for Language Detection is `2021-01-05`.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i tried zh, zh_chs, zh_cht . but getting same error (The language code is invalid: zh).